# Charging rate for deep cycle 12v battery

Tags: battery-charging, amperage, 12v

I have a 75 AH deep cycle battery(AGM) and I have a battery charger with 2 modes, 5.5A for car, 2A for motorcycle, as far as I remember, lower charging rate is usually better for longer battery life and better charging, my questions are if what I remember is even true, and if so, does long charging affects the battery? For example, maybe lower charging rate might be better, but if it takes very long to charge it makes it worse?
Long story short, which mode should I use, the 5.5A or the 2A? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

A widely recommended maximum charge rate for lead-acid batteries is about 20% of the Ah rating, so 15 Amps for your 75 Ah battery.  So use the 5.5 Amp setting.

Comment: Maximum charging rate makes sense, but does it matter for example if I charge it with 5.5A or 2A? Thanks anyway for the reply :)

Comment: It will charge faster at 5.5 Amp.  I'd only use the 2 Amp setting on very small batteries (under 25 Ah or so).  But you won't damage the 74 Ah battery either way.

Answer (score 3):

The one answer previously given is very vague (kind of a 'sure, 5.5 Ah is fine'). In reality, the best 'all around' true answer is given in the following, which is an answer that meets the 'charge answer' from both Discover and Optima AGM/GEL battery manufacturers:

If you are NOT using a microprocessor charger (with multiple automatic 'stage' detection circuitry), understand that there are 4 possible 'charge phases' a GEL/AGM/Flooded battery can be administered. Flooded are the old 'battery acid' batteries where water is often added, and are treated different in the final phase to remove or reduce sulfate crystals and to 'equalize' their charge (between cells).

Each 12v 'car-type' or 'deep cycle' battery has 6 internal cells, and 'technically', engineers confuse users greatly when referencing 'charge rates' as they are usually referring to 'each cell', not the whole battery, when speaking. Knowing that these cells are in series (to be combined in number), to say that 'they can take no more than 2.43 volts per cell is actually telling you that you can charge them at a rate up to 6 x 2.43 volts when you connect your charger (14.58 volts from your charger into them). This is SOMEWHAT high, but is what both manufacturers use as an 'upper limit' to prevent life-shortening due to overheating during the charge cycle.

Secondly, and far more important is what you asked...and that is 'how many Amperes should I charge the batteries at, and for how long?'
This question is generally answered by saying 'no more than 2 x 2.4 Ah (amp-hours) per cell...or 6 x 2 x 2.4....or no more than 28.40 Amp-Hours per battery, up to approximately 1/4 (0.25) of the battery's rated Amp-hours...so, a 100-Ah deep cycle battery could be charged up to 100 * 0.25 or 25-Amp-hours charge at 14.58 volts...so if you have a 100 Amp-hour battery, you can charge it at 25 amps at a given 14.5 volts for around 5-hours (testing for when it reaches approximately 14 volts at the battery posts), and be at or near 100% retained charge.
Saying this, the condition of your battery is VERY important at its 'state of discharge' (when it's dead) when you start charging it. For a deep cycle, some batteries (deep cycle, ONLY) can be taken down to as low as 2-volts, and be recovered with what is deemed a 'deep cycle recovery', which is to cut the charge amperage to 1/2 the maximum (in our prior example, this would be 12.5 amps at 14.5 volts) for 3-5 hours...until you raise the potential voltage back to 10.5 volts...this is a 'magic number' for charging 12v batteries, as it is where most 'starter batteries' (vs Deep Cycle) are deemed 'dead', or unable to achieve their designed task of starting a car. Once you arrive at a post-measured 10.5 volts, you can then go 'full charge' (25 amps, in our given example) at 14.5 volts, until you reach full recovery.

All of this math is, of course, based on the given 100-Ah Deep Cycle rating. If you are working with the 'far more prevalent' 20-Ah Deep Cycle rating, then you'd have to go through the numbers yourself for your own use...but generally, it would take your recovery down to 5-Ah 'full charging' and 2.5 Ah for 'deep discharge recovery' to 10.5 volts first.  The reason you are doing this, is because excessively fast charging creates TREMENDOUS HEAT...and heat kills a battery FAST...as in 80% of its life sort of 'death'...you burn it up, you warp the plates, and you create TONS of sulphate crystals which diminish the maximum amount of 'charge retention' it would otherwise be capable of. Something you do NOT want to do to a $200 or more battery!
AGMs are quite a bit more tolerant of 'deep discharge recovery', but it is smartest to invest in a microprocessor charger if you are working with AGMs or GEL batteries, as AGMs (especially) are VERY FICKLE about heat damage in 'high rate charging'...GELs are far more tolerant...but for $500 or more for a decent GEL battery, they should be...and they STILL benefit from microprocessor chargers...as the microprocessor is constantly measuring charge condition, rate, temperature, etc. and adjusting amperage (some even vary voltage, as well) to optimize maximum battery life for you.

I have worked with Class 5-8 trucks through most of my career, and battery banks are difficult to design and plan for...especially when some unknowing soul throws a 1960's 50-Ah charger on a $2,000 battery bank and fries every battery in the tray in one moment of 'but this is the way we used to do it'...well, you can smoke 'em if you own 'em...but it's an expensive, foolish move to do so. The old rule is still generally the new rule...you're not going to get a 12v battery of any capacity charged in less than 10-hours...which goes against the reasoning of many who don't fully understand batteries, and think that 'if they could discharge the whole battery bank in 2-hours, why can't they charge it that fast too?'
Explaining Peukert's Curve (lifespan of a battery against a known load) is beyond this article...but suffice it to say, it's actually harder to explain charging science than the rather-complex equation that drives Peukert's Discharge Curve.